# React Infinite Scroller - Two children with the same key. loadMore function being called twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build an infinite scroll of posts similar to facebook using react-infinite-scroller. However, it's giving me the same error multiple times in the console -

> "Encountered two children with the same key, `shdj1289`. Keys should
>   be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates.
>   Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted —
>   the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version."

This is the Render function

```js
render() {
        const { loading, userData, circleData, redirectToLogin, posts } = this.state;
        return redirectToLogin ? <Redirect to="/" /> : (
            <Container>
                <h1>Hi {userData.firstName}</h1>
                
                <InfiniteScroll
                    loadMore={this.fetchPosts}
                    hasMore={this.state.hasMore}
                    useWindow={false}
                    loader={<div key={0}></div>}
                >
                    {posts.map(p => {
                        return (<Post key={p.postIdentity} data={p} />);
                    })}
                </InfiniteScroll>
            </Container>
        )
    }
```

This is the fetchPosts function -

```js
fetchPosts = () => {
        const postQuery = {
            "PageIndex": this.state.start + 1,
            "PageSize": this.state.count,
            "Id": "shjhdjs"
        }
        request({
            url: 'http://www.example.com/posts',
            method: 'POST',
            data: postQuery
        }).then((res) => {
                if(res.data.length === 0) return this.setState({ hasMore: false });
                this.setState({ start: this.state.start + 1, posts: this.state.posts.concat(res.data)});
        }).catch((err) => console.log(err))
    }
```

This is the initial state -

```js
state = {
        start: 0,
        count: 10,
        hasMore: true
    }
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong? Whenever I run this code, the posts in page 1 get rendered twice and I see these errors in the console -

[image]

As you can see the request with PageIndex = 1 is being called twice which is the reason the warnings are popping up.

Not sure what I'm missing. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: it looks like a bug of infinit-scroller lib. I have almost the same situation, when callback function, which loads more results, calls several times instead of 1 time

Answer (score 1):

This is a late response but hopefully will help others with the same issue. I had a similar issue with duplicate data loading when implementing a similar package, the [React Infinite Scroll Component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroll-component). What worked for me after some research and debugging was remembering that `setState` is asynchronous and may be batching state changes. Try changing the form of `setState` to accept a function instead of an object (React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)):

```
//in your fetch call
this.setState((previousState) => ({ start: previousState.start + 1, posts: previousState.posts.concat(res.data)}));
```

Hope that helps some folks!

Answer (score 0):

Just change key value then your problem will be solved

```
{posts.map((p,index) => {return (<Post key={index} data ={p}/>})}
```

Comment: Just change key value then your problem will be solved

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32686571)

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old question, please explain how it complements the other answer.

Comment: This worked for me. In my example, I'd get duplicates appearing after changing the sort order a few times. Creating a key which combined the array index as well as the item's ID did the trick.

`key={\`${index}_${user.id}\`}`