# Warning: Encountered two children with the same key for react infinite scroll

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, infinite-scroll

I am making an infinite scroll component using React's IntersectObserver. It's working great, except for the error: `Warning: Encountered two children with the same key`

```
      {allDogs?.map((dog) => (
          <Fragment key={dog?.adopterAttribute?.id}>
            {content here}
          </Fragment>
```

In my useEffect hook I set the dog list this way:

```
       setAllDogs((previousDogList) => [
          ...(previousDogList ?? []),
          ...newDogs,
        ]);
```

I have found this question in stack overflow, but most of the solutions talk about how [setState is async, so use a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54750196/react-infinite-scroller-two-children-with-the-same-key-loadmore-function-bein) which I am already doing. Another mentions using [index for the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26088810/how-to-avoid-children-with-same-key-when-replacing-state-in-reactjs-component), but I read elsewhere that that is an anti-pattern. How else could I go about solving this?

Comment: Choose a better key? Without knowing your data model I can't say what that would be, but perhaps the id of the dog, not the adopter? Or create a composite key that is always unique?

Comment: I can't answer for certain without full context. 
But I assume a person may adopt multiple dogs, if this is the case, then `dog.adopterAttribute.id` would duplicate eventually. As mentioned above, you should work with a unique identifier for the dog. If none is available, build a composite one when creating the key

Comment: That's a warning, not an error. Can you share the `allDogs` state/data that you are attempting to render? You really just need to select a better field property to use as a React key; they need only be unique among sibling elements.

Comment: These are unique keys, I think it's because of the building of the array/infinite scroll that it re-detects the same key.

Comment: If React is detecting a duplicate key amongst the mapped sibling components/elements then they are by definition not unique. As others have pointed out, you are mapping dogs, so assuming no duplicate dogs then using a dog id value is better for a React key.

Answer (score 0):

First what I did was to change the key to  a template string.

```
key={`${dog?.adopterAttribute?.id} + ${index}`}
```

Then once the errors/warnings were gone, I could see the final `allDogs` data that was coming through, and realized there were some duplicates afterall, meaning that the error was triggered correctly.

Comment: Using  indexes as keys is not ideal: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59518082/15038439 If possible, giving your `dog` an id would be even better, if that's possible,